# In ACF WordPress, using the Twentyten theme, how can I add subcategories in a checkbox field?

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields, twenty-ten-theme

I have a checkbox field like this:
[image]

But I need two lines that are NOT checkboxes (and not clikable), just text, like that (this is the same question, but done on word, with sub titles like I want) :
[image]

From my UI, I cannot see that option:
[image]

Is there a way to say to the field "those lines are not checkboxes"? By, I don't know, maybe a code, like using something else than ":"?

If you have any idea on how I could do this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet for this would be to take each of the main titles:

Produits du Lab. De Montreal:

and

Produits de HAL:

and make them into a checkbox group

Then make separate checkbox groups for each of the "children" of your top tier checkboxes. Have those "children" appear based on what "parent" is checked, using the conditional settings in ACF.

Comment: That will work, but I am really trying to have all the checkboxes in the same field for data analysis later on. If there is no other way I might think about it or simply remove the subtitles, but it's not what I would like to have. Thank you anyway.